# Limit $ \lim_{x \to a}\left(\frac{a^x - x^a}{x-a}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits-without-lhopital

Need to obtain

$$ \lim_{x \to a}\left(\frac{a^x - x^a}{x-a}\right) $$

I used $ t = x - a$ to obtain 
$$\lim_{t \to 0}\left(\frac{a^a(a^t - 1)}{t}\right) = a^a\ln(a)$$

as I though asymptotically $ (a+t)^a = a^a $ as t approaches 0.

However, the answer is $ a^a\ln\left(\frac{a}{e}\right) $

Note: I will do not accept any answers which use Hospital rule (I'm in the part of the course there this is not covered, so this can be solved other way). Please answer in terms which math beginner knows.

Comment: When $t\to0$, $a^{a+t}-(a+t)^a=a^a(a^t-(1+t/a)^a)$ with $a^t-1\sim t\log a$ and $(1+t/a)^a-1\sim t$ hence you cannot replace bluntly $x^a$ by $a^a$.

Comment: Have you already covered the definition of derivative of a function?

Comment: @DonAntonio, no, just limits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute

$$t:=x-a\,,\;\;\text{so that}\;x\to a\implies t\to0$$

and from here

$$\frac{a^{t+a}-(t+a)^a}t=\frac{a^a\left(a^t-\left(1+\frac ta\right)^a\right)}t=$$

$$=a^a\left(\frac{a^t-1}t-\frac{\left(1+\frac ta\right)^a-1}t\right)\xrightarrow[t\to0]{}a^a\left(\log a-1\right)$$

since (hope the following is also a basic, elementary limit)

$$\frac{\left(1+\frac ta\right)^a-1}t\xrightarrow[t\to0]{}1$$

Comment: I assume we use $(1+\frac{t}{a} - 1)((1+\frac{t}{a})^{a-1} + ... 1^{a-1}) = \frac{ta}{a}$

Comment: @JoeHalfFace That works fine if $\;a\;$ is a natural number, but not otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly the asker assumes. I'll assume that the derivatives are known.

First observe that the expression you have is:

$$ \frac{a^x -a^a}{x-a} -\frac{x^a -a^a}{x-a} $$

Now use definition of the derivative to conclude.

Specifically, the first summand tends to the derivative of $a^x $ at $x=a$, equal to $a^a \ln a$. The summand tends to the derivative of $x^a$ at $x=a$, equal to  $a a^{a-1}=-a^a$. Therefore the limit is the difference between these two derivatives:

$$ a^a (\ln a -1) = a^a \ln (\frac a e ).$$

Comment: The OP said he doesn't yet know derivatives...

Comment: no derivatives...